# What does "I'm sad but that's cool, right?" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across the sentence

> "I'm sad but **that's cool**, right?"

Does the **"that's cool"** part mean that

> "I'm sad but **it's fine**, right?"

Or

> "I'm sad but **being sad is cool**, right?"

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it means exactly what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm sad, but that's normal (= a normal reaction to the situation in question).